# Opening a PDF file from within a table

Tags: php, pdf, button, html-table

Here is the code I have:

```
    foreach ($positions as $position) 
    {
        print("<tr>");
        print("<td>{$position["Post Date"]}</td>");
        print("<td>{$position["Description"]}</td>");
        print("<td>{$position["Link"]}</td>"); //shows location of the file
        print("<td>{$position["File Name"]}</td>");
        $file = rawurlencode($position["File Name"]);
        print("<td><input type=button name=open value='Open File'
        onclick=window.open(...);></td>"); // missing code to open pdf
        print("</tr>");
    }

?>
```

With this I am creating a table listing all pdf files downloaded to a specific directory (localhost/pdfs/*.pdf). Next to listed file name on a page listing all of them in form of a table I have a button which should open that pdf file on click. Why button? Because I tried making that file name a link last few days and that didn't work... So I have two questions:

1. More elegant would be to open that file through a link, if you have a solution to this...
2. Make my button work... file can open with a standard pdf viewer, does not need to be in browser.

Any help will is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open), `window.open()`is written like this :

> var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[,
>   strWindowFeatures]);

which means your code should be

```
print("<td><input type=button name=open value='Open File'
        onclick=\"window.open('{$position["Link"]}', 'pdf');\"></td>");
```

Comment: Sorry, that gave me 404 not found error... Can I get it to open with a pdf viewer?

Comment: 404 error means the link given by `{$position["Link"]}` (which we don't know the value, it's on your side) is wrong. I took it because of your commentary here : `print("<td>{$position["Link"]}</td>"); //shows location of the file` I guessed it was not a bad location ;-)

Comment: Thank you and you are of course right. This does display file location in the table/browser, but for some reason browser does not want to open that file... This is what I was banging my head on last few days. .. hence I wondered if I can "force" this to open with a viewer, not browser.